# Google chrome extension onLaunched.addListener not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following problem. When I open my extension, instead of "started" in my console I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLaunched' of undefined.

My code: background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
console.log("started");
});
```

manifest.json

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Opomni me!",
  "description": "Dodatek, ki nas opozori na prihajoče dogodke",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "alarms"
  ],

  "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

I also checked all the answers on stackoverflow already and I couldn't figure it out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: `chrome.app.runtime` API is not available for extensions, but for standalone apps.

Comment: You don't really need this event .. background page code is run when your extension is first start to work ...so I think you could write it right on background.js

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup